# Algorithmically deducing a composition series for the alternating group $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any (humanly approachable) algorithmic approach to writing down a composition series for a group like $A_4$ apart from *explicitly write down all possible subgroups and pick a maximal normal subgroup at each step*?

The solution to problem 1 in [this PDF](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~tkenney/3030/2012/solutions13.pdf) gives a solution, but I don't find it too helpful:

1. It magically concludes that $K = \{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ is a possible maximal normal subgroup of $A_4$.
2. Similarly, it concludes that *any* cyclic subgroup of order $2$ must be a maximal normal subgroup of $K$. (*)

Could someone please give me an explanation of each of these two steps?

---

**Edit**: (*) has been resolved in the comments now. I'm still looking for an explanation of (1) though.

Comment: I think you need to start by understanding (2) before you consider (1). This is because (2) is quite low-level; I mean, what must a subgroup of $K$ look like, and in particular what are the possible orders of these subgroups?

Comment: @user1729 Well, by Lagrange's theorem a subgroup of $K$ can either have order $1$, $2$, or $4$ I think. We may discard the order $1$ and order $4$ subgroups. Also, every group of 2 is cyclic. However, is there any quick way to conclude that every order $2$ subgroup is normal without explicitly checking it?

Comment: Yes. There are two quick ways. One way is to realised that they have *index* two (index two subgroups are always normal). The other way is to notice that $K$ is abelian.

Comment: @user1729 a) I'm not sure the notion of index makes much sense unless you know a priori that the order 2 cyclic subgroup is normal. This is because "index" is defined as the number of cosets of a normal subgroup $H$ in a group $G$. b) Okay, I see that $K$ is abelian. But how do you conclude from there that the order 2 cyclic subgroup is normal? Which particular theorem are you using?

Comment: I see I was wrong about (a) at least. Index is defined as the number of cosets of a subgroup $H$ (which may or may not be normal) in a group $G$. As for (b), I see that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks for the help regarding (2)! Could you possibly answer (1) now.

Comment: Firstly, for finite groups the index of $H$ in $G$ is simply $|G|/|H|$ (presumably this is somewhere in your notes/book). So in (2) we have $4/2=2$. For (1), this observation about index gives you that $K$ is maximal in $A_4$, as $|K|=4$ and $|A_4|=12$ so $K$ has index $12/4=3$ in $A_4$. Then: subgroups of prime index are always maximal (why?). So...*any* subgroup of order $4$ is a nice candidate for a maximal normal subgroup of $A_4$, as its *automatically* maximal. Does that help? (Normality seems less obvious; I haven't tried.)

Comment: @user1729 Okay, so maximality follows from $|G:K| = |G:H||H:K|$ (cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup#Properties)). Well, now normality remains. I hope someone can come up with an elegant method to show normality. Could Sylow's theorems be helpful somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a)  $A_4$ is a group of order 12. Now, the subgroups of $A_4$ must have an order that divides 12. So, nontrivial subgroups have potential orders: 6,4,3, and 2. Since $K$ is the Unique 2-Sylow subgroup, it must be normal. The quotient group has order 12/4 = 3 and therefore is cyclic(even stronger than abelian).

(b) Now, inside of $K$ we know a cyclic subgroup of order 2 must exist. This can be seen from Cauchy's Theorem which states for any prime, p, that divides the order of a group, there exists an element of order p. We know that the subgroup generated by the element of order 2 must be normal inside $K$ as its index is 2.

Comment: i) How do you know that $K$ is the *unique* Sylow 2-subgroup? ii) Even if you know that $A_4$ has a *unique* Sylow 2-subgroup how do you know it's specifically $K$? iii) How do you know that any unique Sylow 2-subgroup *has to be normal*?

Comment: A unique Sylow subgroup is normal iff it is unique. To see this all p -Sylow subgroups are conjugate. If there is only one of them, then it is conjugate to itself only.  Therefore it is normal. Sometimes you can make a counting argument to see it is unique. In this case, it might not be so easy.  Knowing the basic subgroups of $A_4$ would help, as you would see there is only one subgroup of order 4. Since it has order 4, it is a 2-Sylow subgroup and since it is unique, it is normal. Also, you know it is a 2_Sylow subgroup since 2^2 *3 = 12 which is the order of $A_4$.

Comment: "Knowing the basic subgroups of $A_4$ would help, as you would see there is only one subgroup of order 4." Well, is there any way to know that there is only one subgroup of order 4 and determining which one it is, apart from memorizing them or writing them all down? :)

Comment: In this case, I don't see an easy way. In other examples, it might be easier.  Sometimes the divisibility condition is enough to see this. Take a group of order 51 = 17*3. In this case, both Sylow subgroups are unique. In other  cases you may have to consider a different number of p-Sylow subgroups and see that there would be too many of them for them to fit inside a group of a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm jotting down the points I gathered from the comments and other Math SE answers.

Every finite group $G$ has a composition series, so we will try to find a composition series for $A_4$ and then analyze it further. For that, we first need to find a maximal normal subgroup of $A_4$. By Lagrange's theorem, subgroups of $A_4$ can only be of cardinality $1, 2, 3, 4$ and $6$ since $|A_4| = 12 = 2^2.3$ and we know that any subgroup of prime index is maximal. So subgroups of cardinality $4$ are potentially good candidates for maximal normal subgroups. Moreover, from Sylow theory, we know that a subgroup of order $2^2=4$ must exist. In fact, we can exclude cardinality $6$ subgroups (which are the only other possible subgroups having a cardinality that allows for a prime index, i.e., $2$) as they do not exist in $A_4$. The last result is non-trivial, of course.

Any permutation $\sigma \in A_4$ may be decomposed as $\sigma = \sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots\sigma_r$ where each $\sigma_i$ is a $k_i$-cycle and any two $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ are mutually disjoint cycles. The $k_1 + \ldots + k_r = 4$ and there can only be a limited number of cycle structures for any element in $A_4$. We can straightaway discard 4-cycles and standalone 2-cycles because they're not even permutations. The remaining cycle structures correspond to the partitions $4 = 3 + 1$ (3-cycles) and $4 = 2 + 2$ (disjoint double transpositions) and $4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$ (identity permutation). So any non-trivial element in $A_4$ can either be a 3-cycle or a disjoint double transposition.

Cardinality $4$ subgroups in $A_4$ can only be isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$ (Klein 4-group) and not to $C_4$ as there exists no element of order $4$ in $A_4$ (since the only possible elements of $A_4$ are either 3-cycles having order $3$, disjoint double transpositions having order 2 or the identity, as we proved in the previous paragraph). In a Klein-4 group, all the non-identity elements have order $2$. So we can write down all subgroups of $A_4$ having cardinality $4$ having $3$ order $2$ elements.

Note that there are already $\binom{4}{3}\times 2 = 8$ 3-cycles in $A_4$, because there are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of picking an element from $A_4$ and because a 3-cycle like $(123)$ is distinct from $(132)$. So there are only $3$ elements of order $2$, and thus, $A_4$ has only one subgroup of cardinality $4$ which is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$. Alternatively, we can directly find the number of disjoint double transpositions using the formula $\binom{4}{2}/2 = 3$, because $\binom{4}{2}$ is the number of ways of picking $2$ elements forming a 2-cycle from $A_4$ and we divide by half as $\binom{4}{2}$ counts each disjoint double transposition twice. To be more explicit, the *unique* cardinality $4$ subgroup in $A_4$ is $K = \{(), (12)(34), (1,3)(2, 4), (1, 4)(2, 3)\}$.

We know that a Sylow p-subgroup is normal iff it is unique. Since $K$ is our unique Sylow 2-subgroup of cardinality $4$, it is necessarily normal in $A_4$. We also know that it is maximal as $K$ has a prime index in $A_4$. So $K$ is in fact a maximal normal subgroup in $A_4$ and the first term of the composition series after $A_4$ itself. Now inside of $K$ a cyclic subgroup of cardinality $2$ must exist by Cauchy's theorem. Moreover, a subgroup of prime index $p$ in a group of cardinality $p^n$ is normal. So any cardinality $2$ cyclic subgroup generated by one of the order $2$ elements in $K$ is normal in $K$. Maximality is ensured as the index of such a subgroup is prime. Such a subgroup is also necessarily isomorphic to $C_2$.

So the three possible composition series are:

$$A_4 \rhd K \rhd \{(),(12)(34)\} \rhd \{()\} = 1$$

$$A_4 \rhd K \rhd \{(),(13)(24)\} \rhd \{()\} = 1$$

$$A_4 \rhd K \rhd \{(),(14)(23)\} \rhd \{()\} = 1$$

We will show that although the factors in the composition series are cyclic $H = \{(),(12)(34)\}$ (or $\{(),(13)(24)\}$ or $\{(),(14)(23)\}$ for that matter) are not normal in $A_4$. So no composition series is invariant.

In any group, a subgroup is normal if and only if it is a union of conjugacy classes. In $A_n$ the conjugacy classes consist exactly of all even permutations of a given cycle structure. So the conjugacy classes in $A_4$ are:

1. The class of 3-cycles, cycle structure $(abc)(d)$ corresponding to the partition $4 = 3 + 1$. There are $8$ elements in this class.
2. The class of product of two disjoint transpositions, cycle structure $(ab)(cd)$ corresponding to the partition $4 = 2 + 2$. There are $3$ elements in this class.
3. The class of identity, cycle structure $(a)(b)(c)(d)$ corresponding to the partition $4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$. There is $1$ element in this class.

So the cardinality of a normal subgroup of $A_4$ must be a sum of some of the numbers $1, 3, 8$ and *must* include $1$ which corresponds to the identity class. Hence, we cannot have a normal subgroup with cardinality $2$, like $H = \{(), (12)(34)\}$ in $A_4$. However, we can see that the factors in the composition series are still cyclic as $(C_2\times C_2)/C_2 \cong C_2$ and $A_4/(C_2\times C_2) \cong C_3$. So $A_4$ is certainly polycyclic as it has a composition series with cyclic factors but it's not supersolvable as it doesn't have an invariant composition series.