# Abelianization of the alternating group $A_4$ is the cyclic group $C_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there a simple way to see that the [abelianization](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Abelianization) (first derived quotient) of $A_4$ is $C_3$ without having to explicitly list all the elements of $A_4$ and then find all the pairwise commutators of the elements in $A_4$?

Comment: Think about the subgroup $V$ of $A_4$.

Comment: It isn't really trivial to see that $V$ is a maximal normal subgroup of $A_4$. Or is it? (I know the process to show it though.) Anyway, then?

Comment: $V$ has index $3$ in $A_4$. $3$ is a prime number @Triskelion

Comment: @AnginaSeng Ah, okay. So I get that $V$ is maximal in $A_4$ (as any subgroup having prime index is maximal) and $A_4/V \cong C_3$. However, even then how can we know for sure that $A_4/V$ is the abelianization of $A_4$?

Comment: Or rather, how to be sure that $V$ is the commutator subgroup of $A_4$?

Comment: As $A_4$ is non-Abelian, it must have a non-trivial commutator, and that's an element of $V$. But the non-trivial elements of $V$ are conjugate in $A_4$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng "But the non-trivial elements of  are conjugate in 4." And how does it follow from there that $V$ is the commutator subgroup of $A_4$? Sorry if I'm being thick here.

Comment: Also how do you know that the elements of the non-trivial commutator *must* be elements of $V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3651987/10513), you know that the Kelin-4 subgroup $V$ is normal in $A_4$.
2. $A_4/V$ is cyclic, and so the derived subgroup of $A_4$ is a subgroup of $V$. (The derived subgroup $G'$ of a finite group $G$ is the unique normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/G'$ is the abelianisation of $G$.)
3. Therefore, prove that no proper, non-trivial subgroup of $V$ is normal in $A_4$. It then follows that $A_4'=V$, and the result follows.

You can either prove that $V$ contains no such subgroup by some clever method, or attack it by hand, by conjugating by some elements of $A_4$. This latter approach is much quicker than the idea you suggest in your question :-)